# Using groupby to find previous year information

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am working with a pandas dataframe that has the following form:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'year': [2016,2017,2017,2018,2019,2017,2018,2019,2018,2019],
                  'Name':['A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','C','C'],
                  'It':[1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
                  'Val1':[5,8,1,1,4,2,6,2,7,10]})
```

I am trying to do some kind of modeling to predict Val1 based on previous years data.  To do so, I want to create a new dataframe, that would have the same exact index and Name, but it would have the Val1 from year-1.  There are also different possibilities for the 'It' (customer iteration, 1 means they are in the system 1 time for the year, 2 is 2 times and so on.

My approach is below.  I loop through the rows, try to match up the Name and year columns, check if it is empty or if there are multiple customers per year.

This is very slow.  My actual application has another df that gets searched (in my loop it would be `df['Val2'] = otherDF.loc(otherDF.name ==rows.Name)` -- which I am currently working on figuring out the merge).
But this approach is slow and I was wondering if I can just kind of make use of groupby and shift to extract the previous year info (but then how to fill in?

```
list_of_frames = []
for rows in df.itertuples():
temp = df.loc[(df.Name==rows.Name) & (df.year == rows.year-1),:]
#Check if It exists
if temp.empty:  #Fill Values with Zeros For Now
    temp.loc[0,'Name'] = rows.Name
    temp['year'] = rows.year-1
    temp['It'] = 1
    temp['Val1'] = 0
    temp.index = [rows.Index]
    list_of_frames.append(temp)

else:
    #Check how many times they appear
    if len(temp.index) != 1: 
    # Just add the data together
        temp = temp.groupby(['Name','year']).agg('sum').reset_index(drop=False)

        temp['year'] = rows.year-1
        temp['It'] = 1
        temp.index = [rows.Index]    
        list_of_frames.append(temp)

    else :

        temp.index = [rows.Index] 
        list_of_frames.append(temp)

last_year_data = pd.concat(list_of_frames,sort=False).drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: Do a merge: `df.merge(df.assign(year=df.year-1), on=['Name','year'], how='left')`.

Comment: So that gives me new columns in df (which I can work with).  So I guess I should deal with the multiple indices first (combine the original df o have 1 row per person per year) then do the merge as you suggest ?